# If $H$ is a orthonormal matrix and $u$ is a vector such that $||u||_2=1$, does there exist some $C$ such that $||Hu||_\infty\le C||u||_\infty$?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $H$ be a orthonormal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be a vector such that $||u||_2=1$. Does there exist some constant $C>0$, independent of $N$, such that $||Hu||_\infty\le C||u||_\infty$?

Comment: Did you mean $||Hu||_\infty\leq C||u||_\infty$?

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want something that works for all matrices $H$ and all $u\in S^{N-1}$.

For any $v\in S^{N-1}$ there is orthogonal $H\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ so that $Hu = v$.

Therefore what you wrote is equivalent to existence of $C>0$ such that $1 = \sup_{v\in S^{N-1}}||v||_\infty\leq C||u||_\infty$ for all $u\in S^{N-1}$.

But in that case, since $\sqrt{N}||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}, ..., \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}})||_\infty = ||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}, ..., \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}})||_2 = 1$, we would have $1 \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}$ for all $N$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such dimension-independent constant. There exist orthonormal matrices all of whose entries are $\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{N}}$. They are called Hadamard matrices. (It is not known whether they exist in every dimension, but it is known they exist for infinitely many dimensions, and it is easy to construct them for every dimension which is a power of $2$)
Such a matrix will map some of the vertices of the cube $[-1,1]^N$ (namely, each one of its rows, multiplied by $\sqrt{N}$) to a vector that has at least one coordinate equal to $\sqrt{N}$. See also Jakobian's answer.